# Filter product collection for Criteo Tags in category page: module setup (config.xml)

Tags: magento-1.7, module, category, configuration

I'm implementing Criteo Tags in my store,
Criteo Tags must be put inside the header, for the category page I must get the Sku of the first 3 product listed in the page.

I'm using a module that get the list of sku using this code

```
public function getTopProducts() {    
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();  

    $i = 0;
    $list = array();
    foreach ($layer->getProductCollection() as $product) {
      $list [] = $product->getSku();
      if ($i++ >= 2) {
        //stop after 3rd element
        break;
      }
    }

    return json_encode($list);
  }
```

But in this way i just get 3 sku of the last products created of that category, i must get the real first product that user see in the list that depends on "sort by" select (priv, bame or position), on the direction arrow (hight to low or low to hight)and the page.

UPDATE-----
Trying to implement Cristi's solution:

I've created a new module called CriteoTags with this files and directory:

```
CriteoTags
  - etc
     - config.xml

  - Model
     - observer.php
```

My config is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Lamasas_CriteoTags>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Lamasas_CriteoTags>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <lamasas_criteotags>
                <class>Lamasas_CriteoTags_Model</class>
            </lamasas_criteotags>

        </models>

        <events>
            <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
                <observers>
                    <lamasas_criteotags>
                        <class>lamasas_criteotags/observer</class>
                        <method>criteoList</method>
                    </lamasas_criteotags >
                </observers>
            </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
        </events>

    </global>

</config>
```

My observer is

```
<?php

class Lamasas_CriteoTags_Model_Observer
{
    /**
 * Observe catalog_block_product_list_collection
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
    public function criteoList(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
        if (!$category) {
            return;
        }

        //get head block
        if ($head = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
            $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template', 'criteo.category');
            $block->setTemplate('criteo/category.phtml');
            $head->append($block);
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously I've created the xml file for etc/modules

At last I've created the required template file in
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/criteo/category.phtml

But Doesn't work, what is wrong with the code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

i had the same problem myself - magento loads the collection automatically when rendering the category product list (I think the call was in Toolbar.php, not in List.php, but I don't remember for sure). I solved it by rewriting `_getProductCollection` in List.php. However, I recommend implementing this using events (in my case, I needed that rewrite anyway). Here's how:

Create a new module, I'll call it mymodule. Then create an observer and listen to **catalog_block_product_list_collection**:

```
<core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
    <observers>
        <my_observer>
            <class>mymodule/observer</class>
            <method>addCriteoCategoryTag</method>
        </my_observer>
    </observers>
</core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after>
```

In Observer.php, create the `addCriteoCategoryTag` method:

```
/**
 * Observe catalog_block_product_list_collection
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function extractPricesAndReviewSummary(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if (!$category) {
        return;
    }

    //get head block
    if ($head = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('head')) {
        $block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template', 'criteo.category');
        $block->setTemplate('criteo/category.phtml');
        $head->append($block);
    }
}
```

and last, create the required template file in criteo/category.phtml:

```
<?php 
    $_cat = Mage::registry('current_category');
    if( !$_cat instanceof Mage_Catalog_Model_Category ) { return; }

    $_items = array(); $_k = 0;
    foreach( $_cat->getProductCollection() as $_product ) {
        if( $_k++ == 3 ) { break; }
        $_items[] = $_product->getId();
    }
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/ld.js" async="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.criteo_q = window.criteo_q || [];
window.criteo_q.push(
    {event: "setAccount", account: 'ACCOUNTID'},
    <?php if( $this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>{event: "setCustomerId", id: "<?php echo $this->helper('customer')->getCustomer()->getId(); ?>"},<?php endif; ?> 
    {event: "setSiteType", type: "d"},
    {event: "viewList", item: <?php echo Zend_Json::encode($_items); ?>}
);
</script>
```

Something like this...

**Please note** I haven't tested this exact code anywhere, so don't put it in production without thoroughly testing it.

**Updated per the comments conversation below**: 
To make this work using the method described above (event listener and appending the block), you'll need to rewrite `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_list`:

```
class Local_Catalog_Block_Product_List extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_list
{
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        if ($orders = $this->getAvailableOrders()) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        if ($sort = $this->getSortBy()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        if ($dir = $this->getDefaultDirection()) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        if ($modes = $this->getModes()) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }

        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_block_product_list_collection', array(
            'collection' => $this->_getProductCollection()
        ));

        $this->_getProductCollection()->load();
    }
}
```

This just moves the code that is currently in _beforeToHtml into _prepareLayout. This way, block output won't start and the append will make sense. I think that doing everything in _beforeToHtml is wrong, but from the code comments, I see they might have ran into some issues themselves and used this as a workaround. So make sure to test all areas where catalog/product_list is being used.

Once the rewrite is done, the code should work. I've used a quick test in the template file:

```
<?php

foreach($this->getCollection() as $product) {
    echo $product->getName() . '<br>';
}
```

where `collection` is set from the observer (you can do it like this `setTemplate(...)->setCollection($collection)`). this will show the product names in the head section (actually on screen), so if you sort and change the page of the collection, you'll be able to see the results in the criteo template.

Hope I covered everything.

Comment: Thanks cristi maybe I'm doing something wrong in defining the  module the XML and observer can you please help thanks

Comment: update your question with the module setup (config.xml) and I'll take a look

Comment: I don't see the config.xml anywhere - you just updated the title, i was asking for the complete xml definition pasted in the question body....

Comment: Sorry didn't understood! Now i've done thanks

Comment: the event definition should be in a `<frontend>` tag, which would be a sibling of `<global>`. See if that works, if not, let me know your magento version.

Comment: Hello I've tried to put the <events> outside <global> and inside <frontend>, but doesn't work, when I try to open a category page the system goes in error and gives a white page, i've debbugged and the problem is in this 3 lines of code: 
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template', 'criteo.category');            $block->setTemplate('criteo/category.phtml');
$head->append($block);
I've magento 1.7.0.2 CE
Thanks

Comment: if you get a blank page, then the observer works, so you're on the right path. You'll need to debug thing a bit deeper though - check your server logs or report files for a specific error; you can try enabling developer mode in magento too. those three lines shouldn't fail - are you sure the bug is not in your template file?

Comment: The problem is non tin the template I just clean all code and the problem remains. I've put a log inside the function that tell me if is passed from there (Mage::log ("passed")) and I see that the function is excutet more than 70 times!! obviously it goes in error the secon time that tries to create a block that is already created!.. so I think there is something in the event listener of xml or observer tha run my function critereoList many times

Comment: ok, that makes sense. you probably have multiple listings on the same page (like new, related, category products, etc). you'll need to adapt the code to only create the block once (try using flags) or listen to a different event. the idea is, you want to insert that criteo block in the head only after the product listing has been displayed. an uglier solution would be to write the block directly in the category page or in list.phtml.

Comment: I've now resolved the error and the block is called once and whith the event <catalog_block_product_list_collection>... the problem is that doesn't load my template block. Is it in the right position? I've puttet it inside app/design/frontend/base/default/template/criteo/category.phtml

Comment: yeah, that should work you don;t have the same file in your own theme (as a side note, i would keep custom template files in a custom theme). let me test this myself and will let you know

Comment: it doesn't work because at that point the html above the product list is already generated, so the append() won't change anything. i'll get back with a solution

Comment: i guess the easiest solution would be to add the tracker into before_body_end, instead of the head block.

Comment: unfortunatly i must include it inside the head

Comment: answer updated, let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks I think this is the right way but for me doesn't work, at last i've integrated those tags inside my list page... is not nice but for now it works

Comment: there's another way, i've just used it for something else. i added a placeholder (as a child text block of head), then intercepted the `controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_category_view` and replaced the placeholder with the correct information. The placeholder is just an html comment in this case. not an idea solution, but it's easy and it works fine